# Accrued hours by order in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

The purpose of this measure is to be able to calculate the time it took to update the information daily and thus determine the total hours that passed in case of multiple failures.

Hi there, I have these table.

1. instance_id -> executionID (it's in order)
2. time -> execution time.
3. run_status -> 0 = failed, 1 = correct.

[image]

I Want to know how I can accrued time.
Example, the first execution was correct, but the second wasn't, so I need to calculate the hours that have passed since the last failed execution to the correct one.
In this case it would be
11:53 am -> failed , but  at 12:58 was correct --> time  = 1 hour , 5 minutes.

I need to calculate all the hours that have passed between a fail and correct executions.
In this case the result would be 1:05.
I don't have idea how to correct the measure to get the correct result

```
`Test =
    VAR _instancia = SELECTEDVALUE('Historico Jobs'[instance_id])
    RETURN 
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                ALLSELECTED('Historico Jobs'),
                'Historico Jobs'[instance_id] <= _instancia
                
        ),
        'Historico Jobs'[Hora Finalizacion]
        )`
```

Answer (score 0):

If the jobID's are always increasing with time, you can use the JobID as a surrogate for time (kind of), but I was thinking along these lines to get the most recent fail prior to the current time as of the current value in the evaluation context.

```
    last failed execution time = 
MINX(
    FILTER(ALL('Checks'),
            'Checks'[run_status]=0
            && 'Checks'[Time]>= MIN('Checks'[Time])
    ),
    [Time]
)
```

and then I could just subtract that from the current time stamp (say on the successful values) using DATEDIFF() ... something like DATEDIFF([datetime column],[last fail],"minute") and that will give me a number... like this:

```
Mins Since last fail = IF([run_status]=1,[last failed execution time] - [Time],0) * 24 * 60
```

This is a calculated column, because then I can do integer division to "bin" the time between fails to get something like a helpful count.